# Promises not working for IndexedDB in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, indexeddb, angular-promise

I have an app using IndexedDB.  Originally I made prolific use of callbacks, and decided to clean it up using angularjs promises `$q`.

FAIL.

http://jsfiddle.net/ed4becky/bumm337e/

```
angular.module("IDBTest", []);

angular.module("IDBTest")
.service("initSvc", ['$q', function ($q) {
var svc = this;
svc.dbVersion = 1;
svc.open = open;
svc.deleteDB = deleteDB;
var idb = window.indexedDB;

function deleteDB() {
    return $q(function (resolve, reject) {
        idb.webkitGetDatabaseNames().onsuccess = 
            function (sender, args) {
            if (sender.target.result 
                && sender.target.result.length > 0) {
                var db = sender.target.result[0];
                console.log("deleting " + db);
                var request = idb.deleteDatabase(db);
                request.onsuccess = function () {
                    console.log('database ' + db + ' deleted.');
                    resolve();
                };
                request.onerror = function () {
                    reject();
                };
            } else {
                console.log("Nothing to delete");
                resolve();
            };
        };
    });
}

function open(dbName) {
    return $q(function (resolve, reject) {
        var request = idb.open(dbName, svc.dbVersion);
        request.onupgradeneeded = function (e) {
            var db = e.target.result;
            console.log("creating new " + db.name);
            e.target.transaction.onerror = function (e) {
                console.log(e);
            };
            db.createObjectStore("table1", {
                keyPath: "id"
            });
            db.createObjectStore("table2", {
                keyPath: "id"
            });
            db.createObjectStore("table3", {
                keyPath: "id"
            });
        };

        request.onsuccess = function (e) {
            console.log('database ' + dbName + ' open.');
            svc.db = e.target.result;
            resolve();
        };

        request.onerror = function () {
            reject();
        };

    });
}
}]);

angular.module('IDBTest')
.factory('$exceptionHandler', ['$log', function ($log) {
return function (exception, cause) {
    throw exception;
};
 }]);

angular.module('IDBTest')
.run(['initSvc', function (initSvc) {
initSvc.deleteDB()
    .then(initSvc.open('testDatabase'))
    .then(function () {
        console.log(initSvc.db.name + ' initialized');
    });
}]);
```

This fiddle shows my expectation that

1. Any databases created are deleted.
   then
2. A database is open triggering an onupgradeneeded
   then
3. The database is referenced

Unfortunately the `then` statments seem to get called BEFORE the promises are resolved in the onsuccess methods of the IDB calls.

To recreate, run the jsfiddle with the console open.  May have to run it a couple times to get the exception, but it fails most times, because the last then clause is called before the onsuccess on the database open is called.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is with the Promise Chain. The documentation from Angular is a bit confusing, but it seems as though if the return value of the callback method is a promise, it will resolve with a value; not a promise. Thus, breaking the chain.

**From [Angular Promise 'Then' Method Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q):**

> `then(successCallback, errorCallback, notifyCallback)` – regardless of
>   when the promise was or will be resolved or rejected, then calls one
>   of the success or error callbacks asynchronously as soon as the result
>   is available. The callbacks are called with a single argument: the
>   result or rejection reason. Additionally, the notify callback may be
>   called zero or more times to provide a progress indication, before the
>   promise is resolved or rejected.
>
> This method returns a new promise which is resolved or rejected via
>   the return value of the successCallback, errorCallback (unless that
>   value is a promise, in which case it is resolved with the value which
>   is resolved in that promise using [promise chaining](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/#toc-promises-queues)). It also notifies
>   via the return value of the notifyCallback method. The promise cannot
>   be resolved or rejected from the notifyCallback method.

I'm able to get it to initialize with this:

```
angular.module('IDBTest')
    .run(['initSvc', function (initSvc) {
    initSvc.deleteDB()
        .then(function() {
            return initSvc.open('testDatabase');
        })
        .then(function () {
            console.log(initSvc.db.name + ' initialized');
        });
}]);
```

Comment: This helps http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/#toc-promises-queues

Comment: Yeah, that does help. Thanks! I need to find a totem.